# Eyebrow bone is detached from the head mesh

Tags: rigging, constraints

Exercising facial expression animation with settlers rig... ...and having a problem with keeping the eyebrow bones on the face surface.

The rig and mesh are from Blender Cloud, Settlers. (see links below)

Transforming the L or R eyebrow controller deforms the mesh freely so it can penetrate the head mesh or depart from it.

My question is how can I attach it to the surface, so transformations are constrained to keep it above and on the head surface?

I tried to lock the y transformation, I added a limit distance constraint (target=head, clamp=surface)- both had no effect.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Links:
The uploaded file: [image]

The rig and mesh are from Blender Cloud, Settlers [Gabby Settlers Blender Cloud Link](https://cloud.blender.org/films/settlers/5e8f16fd9e1df355918c30e9?asset=2530)

Comment: Could you share your file? It's hard to know what the problem is without it.

Comment: @R-800 Attached, sorry for the bother. I had to post the question before I could upload the file... and waited, it took some time to process.

Comment: When I use this rig, it behaves exactly the way you seem to be describing as the way you WANT it to behave. When I grab the cube shaped eyebrow controller, the eyebrow rig remains constrained to the head surface. It never departs from the face. Now, if I grab the eyebrow bones directly, those can pulled away from the face. But not if you use the controller. So I don't know what your issue is at this point.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy! All you have to do is add a "Shrinkwrap" constraint to each bone and set the target to the mesh with the head. It'll stick to the surface. One of my favorite modifiers

Comment: It did the job. Thanks. Though, the Master bone was Target Normal Project and the other Near Vertex. When I tried to copy the Master setting (already set by Blender.org) it deformed strangely the eyebrow mesh.